# Doctrine 2 Symfony 2 Getting foreign key entities without mapping

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

so I am fairly new to Symfony and Doctrine. I would like to know if there's a way to ask doctrine what foreign keys are in place, but without having to map relationships in the model.

For example, say you have `CoreBundle:Company` which is ALWAYS going to be present, and then you have `OptionalBundle:Client` which will extend Company with a `@OneToOne` mapping relationship, adding a few more fields in itself. The thing is, that since `OptionalBundle` may not be present, I don't want explicit mapping from `CoreBundle` to `OptionalBundle`.

Now say a user comes along and attempts to delete `Company(5)`. If the entity was fully mapped it would delete both with cascading, but since the bundle is not going to be aware of a mapped relationship it would end up deleting the Company only - I want to produce an error rather than cascading the deletion.

If this is possible quite easily, then I would also want to take it another step further and say, what entities (class and id) have foreign keys that I can show the data to the user, like

```
@CoreBundle:Company(5) ->
    has @OptionalBundle:Client(3) linked, and
    has @AnotherOptionalBundle:Supplier(12) linked
```

My first instinct is to do a custom INFORMATION_SCHEMA lookup for the foreign keys but that will only give me table names...

**PS** I REALLY prefer not to have to use any third party vendors as I like to try and keep the dependencies down, even if it means reinventing the wheel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1**

You could set the `Client` as the owner of the 1-to-1 relationship. However, depending on your use-case it might not be ideal, but if that works for you it would really be the simplest solution, as pointed out by **ABM_Dan**.

Barring that, the best option for you is probably to use [Doctrine event subscribers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html) and to hook on the `preDelete` event, where you would remove the associated `Client`, before the `Company` itself is removed - if cascading the deletion is really what you want.

By default both deletion will be in the same Doctrine transaction, meaning that if something goes wrong when deleting the `Company`, the `Client` deletion will be cancelled.

If you really want to trigger an error instead of this "manual cascading" of sorts, it is also possible in the `preDelete` method of the Doctrine subscriber.

The subscriber class can reside in your optional bundle even though it will act on an event associated to `Company`.

Doctrine event subscribers are separate from the regular Symfony event system. Newcomers often are not aware of its existence, but it can achieve a lot of interesting things.

**Question 2**

Still in your event subscribers, it is possible to hook on the `postLoad` event. This would allow you to request the database and load related entities directly into `Company`. You can create an event subscriber for `Company` in each bundle that requires it.

Although this is possible I really wonder if there might not be a better way. Using [decorators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) might be a better solution. I found a [Doctrine cookbook article](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/decorator-pattern.html) about it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered defining the relationship as owned by the OptionalBundle side?

Answer (score 0):

The only idea I come across is to pre-create class-mapping during Compiler Pass with some fallback type when secondary bundle is absent.

In compiler pass, check whether container has a secondary bundle loaded and use `DoctrineOrmMappingsPass::createXmlMappingDriver` with adjusted path. If found - map with secondary bundle's entity, if not - map it to null (for example).